# How to set source for Image Control where the image resides in application folder

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I am using an image control. i am setting the source for Image control like below.

But the error shows invalid URI.

```
 string strUri = String.Format(@"..\..\Assets\Images\Image001.jpeg"); 
  previewImage.Source = BitmapFromUri(new Uri(strUri));

 public static ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = source;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of .net, it does matter.

Comment: am using .net 4.5 (visual studio 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to specify that it is a relative URI by setting `UriKind.Relative`:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"..\..\Assets\Images\Image001.jpeg", UriKind.Relative);
```

---

That said, your `BitmapFromUri` method might be redundant (unless you have a reason to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`). You may probably as well use the BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri parameter:

```
previewImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

---

Please note also that the above assumes that image file is actually copied to the specified relative path. If it is part of your Visual Studio project, it might perhaps better be loaded as embedded resource via a [WPF Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). You would therefore have to set its `Build Action` to `Resource`.